# Are these circuits equivalent? (Arduino on breadboard)

Tags: atmega328p

Small background: I would print a PCB with an ATMEGA. Per Gammon website instruction (http://www.gammon.com.au/breadboard) we need 2 ceramic capacitors, on both "side" of Atmega, connected to the VCCs and GNDs.

I cannot figure if I can "delete" one capacitor and use schema 1 because the circuit 1 will be equivalent to 2 or not.

[image]

Comment: You physically need both for *decoupling/bypass*. Look up those terms to see why.

Comment: Thank you. So, see the board: http://i.imgur.com/sQInXcP.png . In your opinion is it right connected? Seems to me yes, of course I' talking only the part relative to the two capacitors (and, I know, I could arrange the two layers better than now.... I will redo)

Comment: The point of having 2 caps is to have them as close as possible to the power input pins. Putting them side by side and routing "long" traces defeats the purpose. Please post updates to the question on the question, not in the comments section. (it will likely work with no problems in this application, but since you asked, it's not the correct approach)

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, no.

Think of the circuit diagrams you drew as ideal cases. In reality, there are stray capacitances, inductances and resistances surrounding all of those pins and traces. That's why there are two physically separated caps, and removing one actually matters. The placement of the caps matters, and you should be following the recommendations.

If it were an ideal circuit, then your two diagrams may be electrically equivalent, but there's no such thing as an ideal circuit.

Comment: Thank you. So, see the board: http://i.imgur.com/sQInXcP.png . In your opinion is it right connected? Seems to me yes, of course I' talking only the part relative to the two capacitors (and, I know, I could arrange the two layers better than now.... I will redo)

Comment: According to http://www.gammon.com.au/breadboard - no. The caps should be on either side of the uC.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The decoupling capacitors are there to compensate for variations in voltage that occur when one of the components draws more current than the other. You can't have a single capacitor because that would defeat the purpose of having the these decoupling capacitors for each VCC pin on the Atmega since it won't be able to mitigate the voltage spikes experienced by each respective pin.

wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_capacitor

Comment: This is an incorrect interpretation of the reason for separated decoupling caps. At face value, the "voltage spikes experienced by each respective pin" will be guaranteed equal, since they are shorted together. The real reason that noise will vary from pin to pin is stray passive equivalents.

Comment: That is to say, there may be separate voltage spikes on each of the pins, but that's a symptom of the underlying cause: that the short between AVCC and VCC is not a perfect short, and rather a small resistance.

Comment: Not familiar with the term "stray passive equivalents", I was under the assumption that the capacitors act as voltage buffers      *I keep forget pressing enter submits the comment, let me continue

Comment: If you could point me to some literature on stray passive equivalents I would be most appreciative, still a student and I don't think we've covered this in detail yet.

Comment: In simple terms, the PCB trace isn't a perfect conductor; it acts as a resistor. If it were a perfect conductor then there would be no need for separate caps, and the OP's suggested circuit would indeed be electrically equivalent.

Comment: For some reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_capacitance   and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board#Circuit_properties_of_the_PCB

Comment: And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_element_(electrical_networks)